# Postgres 13 - SCRAM-SHA-256 client password must be a string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have been using Postgres 12 with MD5 as authentication method and have not faced any issues when trying to connect to a database with password. Nor have I faced issues with user authentication when supplying user password.

However, since I have installed Postgres 13 , I have been blocked by this error `client password must be a string`. This is a fresh installation of Postgres. Please note that there are solutions which talk about how to migrate from MD5 authentication to scram-sha-256 by making changes to `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files. But none of them speak about this issue for a fresh installation of Postgres 13.

What should I be looking for to get rid of this error?

[image: scram-sha-256-password-auth-err]

Comment: This looks like a problem on the client side.  What is your client/driver?

Comment: Am using VSCode Powershell terminal to connect to the postgres db. Not sure if that is what you are asking. @jjanes